# Generating a video from images with avimanager is throwing an error

Tags: c#

I am using webclient to get the image data from a url, and trying to generate a video with it like so:

```
        //http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(images);
        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(responseStream);


        //create a new AVI file
        AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(@"C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\tada.avi", false);

        //add a new video stream and one frame to the new file
        //set IsCompressed = false
        VideoStream aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 2, bitmap);

        aviManager.Close();
```

But it cuts out on the following. In the library on this line

```
int result = Avi.AVIFileCreateStream(aviFile, out aviStream, ref strhdr);
```

I get the following error:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: Change your project settings "platform target" to x86....you probably have "Any CPU" at the moment...and that library doesn't provide the right interop wrapping to make calls down to the 64bit AviFile.dll (which is a component of the OS).

Comment: @ColinSmith interesting. That worked. I am going to assume it only works on 32 bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have "`Any CPU`" at the moment...so your app then gets compiled/run as a 64bit process (on a 64bit Windows version).

The problem appears to be that that AVI Wrapper library was probably never tested with a 64bit .NET app....it hasn't defined the "pinvoke" definitions properly so that the parameters are correctly pushed on/popped off the stack when making the 64 bit API calls.

Change your project settings "platform target" to x86...so that you can avoid the issue....and can call the "avifil32.dll" albeit in 32bit mode.

Windows does ship with a 32bit and 64bit of that AVI library so in theory it is possible to call an AVI library when you are a 64bit process....but you need to define the interop/marshalling pinvoke properly.

- c:\windows\system32\avifil32.dll (64bit)
- c:\windows\syswow64\avifil32.dll (32bit)

In 32bit (Microsoft uses the ILP32 data model)...

- an int is 4 bytes
- a pointer is 4 bytes

In 64bit (Microsoft uses the LLP64 or P64 data model)....

- an int is (still) 4 bytes
- a pointer is (now) 8 bytes

(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384083(v=vs.85).aspx)

The mistake that often happens is that "pinvoke" definitions have used "int" when defining pointer types, instead of the more correct `IntPtr` type.

Thus, the "call" works ok on 32bit (because an "int" is the same size as a "pointer")....while on 64bit they are different sizes.

Other things change when you are 64bit too...such as the default boundary alignment...this can change offsets of types within structures - so you have to be careful when you are defining your pinvoke c# structures...so they match.

In case you are interested for the function call `AVIFileCreateStream` its WIN32 signature is as follows:

```
STDAPI AVIFileCreateStream(
   PAVIFILE       pfile,
   PAVISTREAM     *ppavi,
   AVISTREAMINFO  *psi
);
```

And the "types" of its parameters are:

```
typedef IAVIFile *PAVIFILE; // i.e. just a pointer

typedef IAVIStream *PAVISTREAM; // i.e. just a pointer

typedef struct {
  DWORD fccType;
  DWORD fccHandler;
  DWORD dwFlags;
  DWORD dwCaps;
  WORD  wPriority;
  WORD  wLanguage;
  DWORD dwScale;
  DWORD dwRate;
  DWORD dwStart;
  DWORD dwLength;
  DWORD dwInitialFrames;
  DWORD dwSuggestedBufferSize;
  DWORD dwQuality;
  DWORD dwSampleSize;
  RECT  rcFrame;
  DWORD dwEditCount;
  DWORD dwFormatChangeCount;
  TCHAR szName[64];
} AVISTREAMINFO;
```

That wrapper library defined the NET "pinvoke" to `AVIFileCreateStream` using this:

```
//Create a new stream in an open AVI file
[DllImport("avifil32.dll")]
public static extern int AVIFileCreateStream(
    int pfile,
    out IntPtr ppavi, 
    ref AVISTREAMINFO ptr_streaminfo);
```

Immediately, you can see that the first parameter is defined incorrectly.

When the "call is made"....only 4 bytes will be placed onto the stack for the first parameter...instead of 8, then for the second parameter (which is a pointer to a pointer) 8 bytes are pushed (because IntPtr was used) (the address where to "write" an address), third parameter is an address to an AVISTREAMINFO structure.

Thus when `AVIFileCreateStream` is called it accesses those parameters on the stack, but they are basically junk.....it will be trying to use a pointer with the wrong value (i.e. only 4 bytes of the (first parameters) pointers address has come through on the stack...and the remaining 4 bytes (of the 8 byte pointer) are filled from the "next" thing on the stack...thus the pointer address is highly likely to be garbage....which is why you get the access violation.

The way it should have been defined is something like this (note there are other ways to achieve the same):

```
[DllImport("avifil32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int AVIFileCreateStream(IntPtr pfile, out IntPtr ppavi, ref AVISTREAMINFO psi);
```